# Call state class from widget in flutter

Tags: view, flutter, widget, state, stateful

I think I have a flawed architecture but I'm struggling to see how/why. I'm very new to flutter, so bear with me please.

I have a map, and a drawer. I'm loading a list of coordinates in the drawer, and I'd like to do stuff on the map once I press one of those coordinates.

So my problem is that I don't know what to call where to be clean code AND working. Of course I could just expose everything to everyone but that wouldn't solve the main issue : me understanding

My map is drawn in the same place as my drawer, so there I already think I'm cheating but I *think* that's okay. To be honest I'm not even sure that part is really correct.

Drawing the map :

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  var _map = MapView();
  var _stationService = StationService();

  ....

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 4,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.map)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike))
              ],
            ),
            title: Text('Floctta Plus'),
          ),
          drawer: _drawer(),
          body: TabBarView(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: [
              IncrementView(),
              _map,
              Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
              Icon(Icons.directions_bike)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

In my drawer code :

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, position) {
    return ListTile(
       title: new Text(snapshot.data[position].titleFR),
       leading: new Icon(Icons.pin_drop),
       onTap: () {
         _map.GoToStation();     <<= Here, calling the MapView class
       },
    );
  },
),
```

All the MapView.dart code

```
class MapView extends StatefulWidget {
  MapView({Key key}) : super(key: key);


  void GoToStation() {
    print("I'm reaching this point with success!");
  }

  @override
  _MapViewState createState() => _MapViewState();
}

class _MapViewState extends State<MapView> {
  CameraPosition _initialPosition =
      CameraPosition(target: LatLng(50.8267018, 4.3532732), zoom: 10.0);
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  var _markers;

  void AddMarkers(List<Station> stations) {
    setState(() {
      _markers = new List.generate(
          stations.length,
              (index) => Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId(index.toString()),
            position: new LatLng(double.parse(stations[index].latitude),
                double.parse(stations[index].longitude)),
            infoWindow: InfoWindow(
              title: stations[index].titleFR,
              snippet: stations[index].city,
            ),
            icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
          ));
    });
  }

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    _controller.complete(controller);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        GoogleMap(
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          initialCameraPosition: _initialPosition,
          markers: _markers,
          myLocationEnabled: true,
        ),
      ],
    );
    // );
  }
}
```

I think there is enough code.

My question is :

Im in my Mapview class now, and I'd like to call `AddMarkers` that is in my State class. But I can't. I'm not really sure how I'm supposed to proceed.

Should I call the state class directly from the drawer? If so, how?
Should I call the state from the view class ? If so, how?
Should I be doing something else entirely? If so, what ?

Comment: You have a couple ways to do this.  The best way I have found is to use the BLoC pattern.  Basically then you have a repository class which would keep track of your markers and then your GoogleMap would use a stream from the repository which would stream lists of markers.  So every time the markers change you receive an updated list of markers.  https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi1sdWRsariAhVQL6wKHeb4Dg4QFjAAegQIABAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.com%2Fflutterpub%2Farchitecting-your-flutter-project-bd04e144a8f1&usg=AOvVaw2n1Otof-lG_n6H1x-vuEIE

Comment: I've read about BLoC but I've also read that's its too much, too intense for someone who starts. So I tried to stay away from it :/
But I  guess if that's a solution I'll have to get into it eventually :D

Comment: The BLoC pattern is just one design pattern which is a widely used and accepted solution.  I would not suggest staying away from these if you want to create more complex applications as these patterns will speed up your coding and help you create maintainable code.

Answer (score 2):

Right!

I will assume that `MapView` and `Drawer` are in different widget subtrees under Scaffold. One is the `drawer`, the other appears somewhere under `body`.

My understanding is that when someone clicks on a ListTile in the Drawer, the MapView should update.

In general, the principle you want to employ in that case is introducing a 3rd party object to mediate between the 2 components.

```
AWidget <--> SState <--> MapView
```

The most ill-advised approach of it would be to introduce a global variable (please, don't ever do, just mentioning it so that you get the idea). So chit-chat between the ListTiles and your MapView should happen through this mediator object.

Let's call this object SState. (Double SS is on purpose to differentiate from Flutter's State class). This SState will be responsible for keeping track of the params of the map building. (I'm not actually familiar with the insights of your app, so that is completely made up)

So, this indirection of action handling will mean:

```
tap on ListTile in drawer -> update SState object -> let Flutter know stuff happened and should update those widgets that are sensitive to that change (MapView)
```

Updating SState object is easy, it is just a function call/setter call to it. But how do you let Flutter know that it should update MapView? And where should you place that SState object instance so that both can reach it without a global var?

To answer that, there are a number of solutions: `scoped_model`, `InheritedWidget`, `Provider`, `BLoC pattern`. What is common in all of this is that they employ a principle called `lifting state up`. Basically means, that the *SState object* should be created in the tree above both of them.

Provider example:

```dart
class SState with ChangeNotifier {

  String _someMapParam;
  String get someMapParam => _someMapParam;
  set someMapParam(String val) {
    _someMapParam = val;
    if(hasListeners) notifyListeners();
  }
}

// [...] somewhere in your app

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ChangeNotifierProvider<SState>(
    builder: (ctx) => new SState(),
    child: Scaffold(
      drawer: _drawer(),
      body: Consumer<SState>(
        builder: (_, sStateInstance, __) => Text(sStateInstance.someMapParam),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

More details on provider: https://pub.dev/packages/provider